# Python Mido library example does not work

Tags: python, midi

I installed [mido](https://mido.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) with `pip install mido` and tried to execute the example code from the [docs](https://mido.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ports.html#input-ports):

```
import mido

with mido.open_input('SH-201') as inport:
    for message in inport:
        print(message)
```

But I get the following error message:

```
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(libportmidi.dylib, 6): image not found
```

Any idea what I did wrong?

Edit: Is there any other comfortable way to read input from a MIDI device with python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install a backend that interfaces with the MIDI hardware, like [PortMidi](http://portmedia.sourceforge.net/portmidi/). The error message tells you that the backend was not found.

You can install it via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).
In a Terminal, run:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

to install Homebrew. Then, run

```
brew install portmidi
```

to install PortMidi.

Download the [pmdefaults Mac binary](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portmedia/files/portmidi/217/pmdefaults-mac-217.zip/download), connect your MIDI device to your computer, and run pmdefaults (right-click, select Open, since the application is not signed). Select your default MIDI device, click Update Preferences, and quit the application. Start a new Python interpreter. Mido should now work as intended.